# Could not find 'sass-listen' (~> 4.0.0) among 49 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)

Tags: ruby, sass

When i want to run watcher in the VS terminal it gives me the following error:

> Could not find 'sass-listen' (~> 4.0.0) among 49 total gem(s)
>   (Gem::MissingSpecError) Checked in
>   'GEM_PATH=/Users/mohammadullahasrar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4:/Users/mohammadullahasrar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0',
>   execute `gem env` for more information

I installed SASS, npm and node.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have "https://rubygems.org/" as a source to find gems at:

```
`$ gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***
https://rubygems.org/
`
```

If not, you should be able to add it with

```
$ gem sources --add https://rubygems.org/
https://rubygems.org/ added to sources
```

Comment: Thanks @Saif chaudhry, i solved the issues installing:  gem install sass-listen -v 4.0.0